# git + sourcetree : newly cloned git repo is not allowing to switch branches

Tags: git, github, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

I am facing a strange problem where I have cloned a repo from git with no issues and while doing checkout to another branch I am unable to do it as the sourcetree shows '*please commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches. aborting*'

Added to this few font and .png files are getting listed in the list of files which needs to be committed before switching to another branch. But this is a new repo that I have cloned and by no means these files are added in local.

Any suggestions on what could be wrong ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you clone the repo and it has the local copy on your machine. And you're doing checkout to another branch but it doesn't allow you to do. It means you have some files which are not added by you or by building the project.

Just do git status or use any gui tools to see the files it needs a commit. If those *.png files are auto generated due to build you can just ignore it.

How can you avoid those files ending up in git tree, there are two methods but here I suggest you use stash

## Stash

```
git stash
git pull origin master
```

then do

`git checkout "the branch_you_want"`

## Discard the local changes

`git reset HEAD --hard` , this is bit risky command it will remove all the files which is not checkedin becareful before using it and make sure those files are not needed.

Comment: I will try this and check. Thanks